# Replicate constant output based on the occurrance of specific events

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table with events (say X, Y, Z are random events and A, B are the ones I want to track). If I find event A, I want to output 1 on the current and following rows and if I find B I output -1 on the current and following rows, before I find any of them (A or B) I output 0. How do I do that using Hive (SQL)?

```
event | output | ordercol
  X       0         1
  Y       0         2
  Z       0         3
  B      -1         4
  X      -1         5
  X      -1         6
  B      -1         7
  X      -1         8
  A       1         9
  X       1        10
  B      -1        11
  Z      -1        12
```

I know this could be accomplished using joins but I'm looking for a more elegant solution (maybe using Window Functions - I've tried dense_rank() and row_count() with no success)

Comment: You need an additional column to specify row order as an SQL table is just an unordered set of data.

Comment: For simplicity, you can assume that table is already ordered.

Comment: @ThiagoBalbo . . . That is not SQL.  You need an ordering column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [documentation](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11189), you can use `first_value()` and some additional logic:

```
select event,
       (case first_value(case when event in ('A', 'B') then event end, true) over
                      (order by ordercol desc)
             when 'A' then -1
             when 'B' then 1
             else 0
        end)
from e;
```

This capability is called `IGNORE NULLS` in the standard and in other databases.